# Como detener la espera por un elemento al encontrarlo (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, sql, setinterval, timeout

Tengo una duda. Yo tengo el siguiente código para esperar por estos elementos y asignarle esos valores. El problema es que la pagina queda en loop gracias al evento change. Quisiera saber como hago para parar el timeout luego de haber encontrado esos elementos.Gracias!

```js
function waitForElementToDisplay(selector, time) {
    if (document.getElementById(selector) != null) {
        document.getElementById(selector).value = "BM";
        document.getElementById(selector).dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));                   
        return;
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            waitForElementToDisplay(selector, time);
            }, time);
        }
    }

waitForElementToDisplay('form1:layoutPanel1:layoutPanel2:tabSetDirecciones:tabDirPrincipal:layoutPanelDirPrincipal:drpDirTipo_list',100);
waitForElementToDisplay('form1:layoutPanel1:layoutPanel2:tabSetDirecciones:tabDirPrincipal:layoutPanelDirPrincipal:txtDirBarrioCK_field',100);
```

Answer (score 0):

## [window.clearTimeout(timeoutID)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout)

Simplemente utiliza `clearTimeout` para eliminar el `setTimeout` creado.

Pero para realizar eso necesitaras antes definirle un nombre a tu `timeout`.

```
// Crear TimeOut
miTimeout = setTimeout();

// Eliminar TimeOut
clearTimeout(miTimeout)
```

Aunque noto que tu código es algo extraño (o es que estoy algo cansado). Si no lo he entendido mal, creo que lo que intentas realizar es comprobar si `selector` es nulo. En caso de no serlo se ejecuta el bloque de código principal, y en caso de serlo se crea "un bucle" para volver a intentarlo más tarde.

Creo que existen varias formas para solucionarlo, pero en este momento solo se me ocurre que crees un bucle de verdad `setInterval()` en el cual se encuentre tu función, y una vez que se complete esta rompas el bucle con `clearInterval()`.

Ahora no tengo tiempo, pero si me dejas un comentario puede que me acuerde mañana de pensar algo.

Comment: muchas gracias! voy a tratar de implementarlo con intervalos y te cuento despues!. Si, es lo que quiero hacer, que busque un elemento hasta encontrarlo y cuando lo encuentre que pare de hacerlo. Ahora me doy cuenta que no lo hace porque veo que la pagina hace un efecto refresh todo el tiempo y es por el change del evento, asi que lo encontro y no paró.